# enabling parts of const array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, embedded

I have a four`const char[][]` arrays with around 50 elemets each, and each element containing another 40 values, these are to be sent to graphical LCD, to draw a certain letter, number, symbol, ...

Now, the problem is, I am working on an embedded system, with very limited resources. And while all four arrays, were usefull on the project I was working before, where I needed most of the characters, I need only 5 or 10 of them now.

I could go and delete out from the arrays charaters I dont need, but I am hoping there is a better way do disable those charaters from getting written to RAM/FLASH.

I was thinking of using `#ifdef` and `#endif`. But doing this for each element, the code would get messy.

Is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Right now, I have `#ifdef` and `#endif` for bigger parts like:

```
#define ARRAY1_BIG_LETTERS
#define ARRAY1_SMALL_LETTERS
#define ARRAY1_NUMBERS
#define ARRAY1_OTHER

#define ARRAY2_BIG_LETTERS
#define ARRAY2_SMALL_LETTERS
#define ARRAY2_NUMBERS
#define ARRAY2_OTHER

...
```

But, I would still need more fine controll over the content.

**EDIT2:**

This is one of the (smaller) arrays:

```
const char writting_8x8[][9] = {
    #ifdef ARRAY1_OTHER
    {32, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0},                        /*   */
    {45, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0},                        /* - */
    {46, 0 , 0 , 96 , 96 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0},                      /* . */
    {58, 0 , 0 , 108 , 108 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0},                    /* : */
    {61, 0 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 0 , 0},                   /* = */
    #endif
    #ifdef ARRAY1_NUMBERS
    {48, 0 , 62 , 81 , 73 , 69 , 62 , 0 , 0},                   /* 0 */
    {49, 0 , 0 , 66 , 127 , 64 , 0 , 0 , 0},                    /* 1 */
    {50, 0 , 98 , 81 , 73 , 73 , 70 , 0 , 0},                   /* 2 */
    {51, 0 , 34 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 54 , 0 , 0},                   /* 3 */
    {52, 0 , 24 , 20 , 18 , 127 , 16 , 0 , 0},                  /* 4 */
    {53, 0 , 47 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 49 , 0 , 0},                   /* 5 */
    {54, 0 , 60 , 74 , 73 , 73 , 48 , 0 , 0},                   /* 6 */
    {55, 0 , 1 , 113 , 9 , 5 , 3 , 0 , 0},                      /* 7 */
    {56, 0 , 54 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 54 , 0 , 0},                   /* 8 */
    {57, 0 , 6 , 73 , 73 , 41 , 30 , 0 , 0},                    /* 9 */
    #endif
    #ifdef ARRAY1_BIG_LETTERS
    {65, 0 , 126 , 17 , 17 , 17 , 126 , 0 , 0},                 /* A */
    {66, 0 , 127 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 54 , 0 , 0},                  /* B */
    {67, 0 , 62 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 34 , 0 , 0},                   /* C */
    {68, 0 , 127 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 62 , 0 , 0},                  /* D */
    {69, 0 , 127 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 65 , 0 , 0},                  /* E */
    {70, 0 , 127 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 1 , 0 , 0},                      /* F */
    {71, 0 , 62 , 65 , 73 , 73 , 122 , 0 , 0},                  /* G */
    {72, 0 , 127 , 8 , 8 , 8 , 127 , 0 , 0},                    /* H */
    {73, 0 , 0 , 65 , 127 , 65 , 0 , 0 , 0},                    /* I */
    {74, 0 , 48 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 63 , 0 , 0},                   /* J */
    {75, 0 , 127 , 8 , 20 , 34 , 65 , 0 , 0},                   /* K */
    {76, 0 , 127 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 0 , 0},                  /* L */
    {77, 0 , 127 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 127 , 0 , 0},                    /* M */
    {78, 0 , 127 , 2 , 4 , 8 , 127 , 0 , 0},                    /* N */
    {79, 0 , 62 , 65 , 65 , 65 , 62 , 0 , 0},                   /* O */
    {80, 0 , 127 , 9 , 9 , 9 , 6 , 0 , 0},                      /* P */
    {81, 0 , 62 , 65 , 81 , 33 , 94 , 0 , 0},                   /* Q */
    {82, 0 , 127 , 9 , 9 , 25 , 102 , 0 , 0},                   /* R */
    {83, 0 , 38 , 73 , 73 , 73 , 50 , 0 , 0},                   /* S */
    {84, 0 , 1 , 1 , 127 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0},                      /* T */
    {85, 0 , 63 , 64 , 64 , 64 , 63 , 0 , 0},                   /* U */
    {86, 0 , 31 , 32 , 64 , 32 , 31 , 0 , 0},                   /* V */
    {87, 0 , 63 , 64 , 60 , 64 , 63 , 0 , 0},                   /* W */
    {88, 0 , 99 , 20 , 8 , 20 , 99 , 0 , 0},                    /* X */
    {89, 0 , 7 , 8 , 112 , 8 , 7 , 0 , 0},                      /* Y */
    {90, 0 , 113 , 73 , 69 , 67 , 0 , 0 , 0},                   /* Z */
    {200, 0 , 56 , 69 , 70 , 69 , 40 , 0 , 0},                  /* Č */
    #endif
    #ifdef ARRAY1_SMALL_LETTERS
    {97, 0 , 32 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 120 , 0 , 0},                  /* a */
    {98, 0 , 127 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 56 , 0 , 0},                  /* b */
    {99, 0 , 56 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 40 , 0 , 0},                   /* c */
    {100, 0 , 56 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 127 , 0 , 0},                 /* d */
    {101, 0 , 56 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 8 , 0 , 0},                   /* e */
    {102, 0 , 8 , 126 , 9 , 9 , 0 , 0 , 0},                     /* f */
    {103, 0 , 24 , 164 , 164 , 164 , 124 , 0 , 0},              /* g */
    {104, 0 , 127 , 4 , 4 , 120 , 0 , 0 , 0},                   /* h */
    {105, 0 , 0 , 0 , 125 , 64 , 0 , 0 , 0},                    /* i */
    {106, 0 , 64 , 128 , 132 , 125 , 0 , 0 , 0},                /* j */
    {107, 0 , 127 , 16 , 40 , 68 , 0 , 0 , 0},                  /* k */
    {108, 0 , 0 , 0 , 127 , 64 , 0 , 0 , 0},                    /* l */
    {109, 0 , 124 , 4 , 24 , 4 , 120 , 0 , 0},                  /* m */
    {110, 0 , 124 , 4 , 4 , 120 , 0 , 0 , 0},                   /* n */
    {111, 0 , 56 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 56 , 0 , 0},                  /* o */
    {112, 0 , 252 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 56 , 0 , 0},                 /* p */
    {113, 0 , 56 , 68 , 68 , 68 , 252 , 0 , 0},                 /* q */
    {114, 0 , 68 , 120 , 68 , 4 , 8 , 0 , 0},                   /* r */
    {115, 0 , 8 , 84 , 84 , 84 , 32 , 0 , 0},                   /* s */
    {116, 0 , 4 , 62 , 68 , 36 , 0 , 0 , 0},                    /* t */
    {117, 0 , 60 , 64 , 32 , 124 , 0 , 0 , 0},                  /* u */
    {118, 0 , 28 , 32 , 64 , 32 , 28 , 0 , 0},                  /* v */
    {119, 0 , 60 , 96 , 48 , 96 , 60 , 0 , 0},                  /* w */
    {120, 0 , 108 , 16 , 16 , 108 , 0 , 0 , 0},                 /* x */
    {121, 0 , 156 , 160 , 96 , 60 , 0 , 0 , 0},                 /* y */
    {122, 0 , 100 , 84 , 84 , 76 , 0 , 0 , 0},                  /* z */
    {154, 0 , 8 , 85 , 86 , 85 , 32 , 0 , 0},                   /* š */
    {158, 0 , 100 , 85 , 86 , 77 , 0 , 0 , 0},                  /* ž */
    {232, 0 , 56 , 69 , 70 , 69 , 40 , 0 , 0}                   /* č */
    #endif
};
```

I choose upfront which of the values I am going to use. So this will probably need to be done with preproccessors somehow...

Comment: From what I understand, in C, all string literals are stored in read-only memory at the beginning of the program. The only way around that would be to use char-literals instead. Without knowing what the contents of the `const char[]` and the way you talk to the LCD, it'll be difficult to come up with a work around.

Comment: Is it really an embedded system? On most embedded systems, const variables are stored in flash, not RAM. Where these arrays end up is quite important to know before starting to optimize things. If they end up in flash and you need more RAM, fiddling with the arrays will solve nothing.

Comment: You can choose whether you want to store it to program memory or RAM. I am just looking for a preprocessor trick, something similiar to what I posted but with more "fine controll".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the start I would recommend you creating list of structs. Additionally your display is 8x8, but you're using only 6x8 (your borders are always 0), and if you replace first one with simply char, you don't have to write comment "what letter is it actually". There's also a trick to add "terminator" (or stop-sequence) to table. Then you don't have to know the array size (I'm assuming you're looping for array to find correct letter). SO:

```
typedef struct _dsp_letter {
  const char ascii;
  const char pixels[6];
} dsp_letter_t;

const dsp_letter_t writing[] = {
  #ifdef ARRAY1_OTHER
    {' ', { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'-', { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'.', { 0 , 96 , 96 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {':', { 0 , 108 , 108 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'=', { 36 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 0 } },
    #endif
    // ...
    { 0 }
}
```

And using looks like:

```
int i = 0;
while (writing[i].ascii != 0) {
    // do stuff, add if or anything
    ++i;
}
```

That change requires changes in display function, but that saved memory may be worth it.

That's one part.
Now, that's the difference between
    const char str[] = "Str";
and
    const char *pStr = "Str";
?

Size!

```
const char str[] = "My long C-style string";
const char *pStr = "My long C-style string";

printf("str: %d vs pStr: %d", sizeof(str), sizeof(pStr));
// str: 23 vs pStr: 8
```

**const char str[]** is allocated on stack and it is actually array, when during run-time data is written.

**const char *pStr** is allocated on heap, and on run-time only **pointer to data** is written to it, and data is in global memory of application.

What does that mean?
*onst char writting_8x8[][9] = { ... };* is allocating huge chunk of memory. On Embedded devices this can be... well, let say I don't recommend it.

What to do?
You can split all that big array into smaller one.

```
typedef struct _dsp_letter {
    const char ascii;
    const char pixels[6];
} dsp_letter_t;

#ifdef ADD_OTHER
const dsp_letter_t other[] = {
    {' ', { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'-', { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'.', { 0 , 96 , 96 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {':', { 0 , 108 , 108 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'=', { 36 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 36 , 0 } },
    { 0 }
};
#endif ADD_OTHER

#ifdef ADD_SMALL
const dsp_letter_t small[] = {
    {'a', { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'b', { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'c', { 0 , 96 , 96 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    {'d', { 0 , 108 , 108 , 0 , 0 , 0 } },
    { 0 }
};
#endif ADD_SMALL
```

Now you can get them all in one place in compile-time or in run-time

compile-time (like your's before):

```
const dsp_letter_t *writting[] = {
#ifdef ADD_OTHER 
    other,
#endif
#ifdef ADD_SMALL 
    small,
#endif
    0
};
```

or run-time:

```
#define ADD_OTHER 1
#define ADD_SMALL 0

int size = ADD_OTHER + ADD_SMALL;
int i = 0;
dsp_letter_t **writting = (dsp_letter_t *writting(malloc)(size* sizeof (dsp_letter_t *writting));

#ifdef ADD_OTHER 
writting[i++] = other;
#endif

#ifdef ADD_SMALL 
writting[i++] = small;
#endif
```

You can work with that :)

Unfortunately I don't know how to do that better without putting **#ifdef ... endif** all oveer the place :/

Comment: An array in global scope (or a `static` one for that matter) won't be allocated on the stack. Given that, splitting it is fairly pointless.

Comment: Yes, global won't be. But no one said it's global. And additionally we can choose in run-time with elements we want (not with `#ifdef ... #endif` but with `if (should_add_small_letter)`.

Comment: The first ideas for the structures of the data are good. The explanation of the data placement is useless, as it's completly wrong.